# How to send dynamic array value in another php file using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Please, help me to solve this problem

When I am trying Single input value  then input value transfer data.php file successfully and I get input value in data.php file  to write this code echo $name=$_POST[‘name’]; but I can transfer input array value in data.php file, actually I have not enough knowledge about jquery. So anyone can help me to solve this problem. What’s the write jquery code for transferring array value in data.php file and what’s the write php code for echo.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function get(){
            $('#age').hide();
            $.post('data.php',{ name: form.name.value }, 

             // this code don't work in array

            // how can i transfer name[] value in data.php file

        function (output){
            $('#age').html(output).fadeIn(1000);
        });
        }

    </script>
    <body>
    <form name="form" action="a.php">

        <input type="text" name="name[]" value="1"/>
        <input type="text" name="name[]" value="2"/>
        <input type="button" value="Get" onclick="get();"/>
    </form>

    <div id="age">

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
<form>
<input name="name[]" value="1" />
<input name="name[]" value="2" />
</form>


$.post('data.php',$('form').serialize(), function(data) {
   alert('success');  /// console.log(data); use this rather than alert with firebug
});


<?php 
//data.php

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';


?>
```

Comment: i modify my code like this :<script type="text/javascript"> function get(){ $('#age').hide(); $.post('data.php',{ name: $('form').serialize() }, function (output){ $('#age').html(output).fadeIn(1000); }); } </script> <?php //data.php echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre>'; ?> but result showArray ( [name] => name%5B%5D=1&name%5B%5D=2 ) I want to get 1 by 1 value. so that I can collect data from database running a query to based on value thanks for help me