# How to get Input value 1 by 1 from jquery to PHP

Tags: php, jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // index.php

    function get(){
        $('#age').hide();
        $.post('data.php',{ name: $('form').serialize() },


    function (output){
        $('#age').html(output).fadeIn(1000);
    });
    }

</script>
<body>
<form name="form" action="a.php">

    <input type="text" name="name[]" value="1"/>
    <input type="text" name="name[]" value="2"/>
    <input type="button" value="Get" onclick="get();"/>
</form>

<div id="age">

</div>
```

but result show

```
Array ( [name] => name%5B%5D=1&name%5B%5D=2 )
```

I want to get 1 by 1 value. so that I can collect data from database running a query to based on value please, kindly  help me

data.php:

```
<?php //data.php 
   echo "<pre>"; 
   print_r($_POST); 
   echo "</pre>"; 
?>
```

Comment: <?php
//data.php


echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";


?>

Comment: You should merge `data.php` code back into your original question, not leave it as a comment.

Comment: Why edit to say you've put the code for data.php in the comments? just add it ;). Anyway, what do you mean by `i want to get 1 by value`?

Comment: How is this different from your earlier [How to send dynamic array value in another php file using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623971/how-to-send-dynamic-array-value-in-another-php-file-using-jquery)? Please note we're not a forum. Put some time in writing your question, so we don't need to ask questions about your question! Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) again, please!

Answer (score 0):

This approach only works when you POST the form normally, using submit.

You now need to unserialize the data:

```
<?php
     var_dump(unserialize($_POST['name']));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I can't unserialize jquery serialize value.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
$.post('data.php',{ name: $('form').serialize() },
```

Says that you post your form (serialized) as the value of key 'name'. While this is possible, I presume you just want your values.

If you take a quick look over at [the jquery post manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) youc an see that you can make an object like this:

```
{ name: "John", time: "2pm" }
```

Just read your form-values with jquery and put them in an object like that, instead of serializing the form.

Comment: I want to unserialize jquery serialize value in php, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but I'm guessing you're not receiving the correct value in your php file?

Try this --
In your HTML file, use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// index.php
function get()
    {
        $('#age').hide();
        $.post('data.php',
        {
            "name1":$('#name1').val(),
            "name2":$('#name2').val()
        },
    function (output){
        $('#age').html(output).fadeIn(1000);
    });
}
</script>

<body>
<form name="form" action="a.php">
    <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" value="1"/>
    <input type="text" name="name2" id="name2" value="2"/>
    <input type="button" value="Get" onclick="get();"/>
</form>
```

and in your php page, have this:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "this is the first input: " . $_POST['name1'] . "<br />";
    echo "this is the second input: " . $_POST['name2'] . "<br />";
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Hope I interpreted your question correctly.

Comment: I want to unserialize jquery serialize value in php, Thanks for help me